# How can I get a speech to text app working with node.js?

Tags: javascript, npm, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm making a discord bot and I think it would be cool for it to have voice commands, but I cant find any npm modules that work. I'm trying to find a speech to text module. If anybody knows anything that would work for that please help! I've tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/speech-to-text but that doesn't seem to work with a node.js app.  :-(  I've also noticed that other people have used node-witai-speech but I don't know how to get an API key.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of my work / employer, I used [Watson STT](https://www.ibm.com/watson/services/speech-to-text/) a few years ago, there is also a [live demo](https://speech-to-text-demo.ng.bluemix.net/) online.

If it's just for a small project, you shouldn't incur in any payment. At the time I used it (a couple of years ago) I did the backend in Java and the frontend in Javascript/Dojo, but the only logic the backend had was to create a new session and pass it to the frontend through REST, then the frontend would create a WebSocket to the Watson service (authenticated through the session).

I had to use Watson and I found it fairly good, as far as I understood also Google exposes some STT APIs in their developer cloud but I never used it! Still, disclaimer applies, I had to use Watson STT because of my employer! ^^